# PCRE Regex: Exclude last portion of word

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to write a regex expression in PCRE which captures the first part of a word and excludes the second portion.  The first portion needs to accommodate different values depending upon where the transaction is initiated from.  Here is an example:

**Raw Text:**

```
.controller.CustomerDemographicsController
```

**Regex Pattern Attempted:**

```
\.controller\.(?P<Controller>\w+)
```

**Results trying to achieve** (in **bold** is the only content I want to save in the named capture group):

> .controller.**CustomerDemographics**Controller

NOTE: I've attempted to exclude using `^`, lookback, and lookforward.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the rule to stop? The last capital letter in the word char sequence?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Yes, that is the rule to stop.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, That worked! Thank you very much for your help. It is much appreciated!

Comment: If you are only using the capture group value, you do not really have to use a lookaround. If that's the case, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69110314/3832970) is also working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match word chars in the *Controller* group up to the last uppercase letter:

```php
\.controller\.(?P<Controller>\w+)(?=\p{Lu})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eqm8EI/1). *Details*:

- `\.controller\.` - a `.controller\.` string
- `(?P<Controller>\w+)` - Named capturing group "Controller": one or more word chars as many as possible
- `(?=\p{Lu})` - the next char must be an uppercase letter.

Note that `(?=\p{Lu})` makes the `\w+` stop before the last uppercase letter because the `\w+` pattern is greedy due to the `+` quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

Also, use

```php
\.controller\.(?P<Controller>[A-Za-z]+)[A-Z]
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/XiPNSx/2).

**EXPLANATION**:

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  controller               'controller'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?P<Controller>           group and capture to Controller:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Za-z]+                any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of Controller group
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
```